# Comparing quarterly data to same time period a year ago

Tags: tableau-api

I have quarterly data for 2018 (Q1-Q3) which I would like to compare with the same time periods from a year ago so 2017 Q1-Q3.

Where it gets a little tricky is that I would like for my workbook to be smart enough in Q1 2019 to know that it only compares for one quarter in 2018 and when Q2 2019 data rolls in it uses 2 quarters and so on and so on.

Is this possible in Tableau?

For those that are interested I have generated some random data in the format of my workbook in Excel for import into Tableau. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzkBEqPfozOOS2ZWd2pkSVViRUh2Z0NXczFES0gwcGY5ZHFz) is the link to the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "when Q2 2019 data rolls in it uses 2 quarters and so on"??
And I assume 2016-Q1, 2016-Q2... are the field names.

Comment: Hi Akshay, what I should have said is that when I am running this analysis in Q3 2019 that it will use Q1 and Q2 2019 data. Regarding fileld names, I have a variable called 'quarter-year' which is a 'date time' that contains all the quarter-year info I.e. 2015-Q4, 2016-Q1......

Comment: Then in that case I think you could use `IF` condition on your date field by comparing with `TODAY` function in Quarter format.

Comment: @akshay thanks, any chance you could elaborate on the IF statement and TODAY statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
IF DATEPART('year',[datefield]) - 1 = DATEPART('year',TODAY())
AND DATEPART('quarter',[datefield]) < DATEPART('quarter',TODAY())
THEN [valueField]
END
```

This will compare with previous year's data.

Comment: @aksahy, thanks for taking the time to reply. Does this calculated field get added to the filter shelf or do I need to run my YoY quick calculation and include it there?

Comment: @TheGoat, you can use calculated field as a filter.